# How to cast a CMRotationMatrix into a float4x4?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-motion

I am building a `Metal` app that uses `float4x4` matrices to rotate 3D objects and/or the world view.

The app is also reading the device `attitude` that can be expressed as a rotation matrix in the `CMRotationMatrix` format (`CoreMotion`).

How can I cast my `attitude.rotationMatrix` into a `float4x4` object?

Comment: Keep in mind that `CMRotationMatrix` is a 3x3 matrix while `float4x4` is obviously a 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an extension that allows you to initialize a `float4x4` from the elements of a `CMRotationMatrix`:

```
extension float4x4 {
    init(_ m: CMRotationMatrix) {
        let x = float4(Float(m.m11), Float(m.m21), Float(m.m31), 0)
        let y = float4(Float(m.m12), Float(m.m22), Float(m.m32), 0)
        let z = float4(Float(m.m13), Float(m.m23), Float(m.m33), 0)
        let w = float4(           0,            0,            0, 1)
        self.init(columns: (x, y, z, w))
    }
}
```

Using it is as simple as calling the initializer:

```
let simdMatrix = float4x4(deviceMotion.attitude.rotationMatrix)
```

This creates a matrix that is suitable for transforming objects whose transformations are expressed *relative to the [reference attitude frame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_processed_device-motion_data/understanding_reference_frames_and_device_attitude)*. You may find that you need to permute the columns so that they match the world coordinate system of your application.