# How to cast a CMRotationMatrix from CoreMotion to be used by a SceneKit camera (or any SCNNode)

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, scenekit, core-motion

I'm trying to use the `attitude` given by `CMHeadphoneMotionManager` to guide a camera inside a `SKSceneView`. If I'm not mistaken, they use difference reference systems, and so the direct initialisation of a `float4x4` matrix [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461135/how-to-cast-a-cmrotationmatrix-into-a-float4x4) would not work without any permutation or change (axis do not match between CoreMotion and SceneKit).

To add some context, and I might well be wrong because I couldn't find the exact reference system, and had to run some tests to find out, the coordinate system used as reference by the `attitude` given by your Airpods (or motion-enabled headphones), goes like this, with positive Y pointing forward from your nose, positive Z pointing up against gravity through your head, and positive X pointing right (at a random direction picked when you start capturing motion): [image]

However, the reference coordinate system for SceneKit have positive Y pointing upwards, and positive Z pointing backwards (assuming you are the camera, which looks towards negative Z). Axis X seems the be the same:

[image]

My linear algebra knowledge at this level is sort of limited, and even though I've been trying for a few days, I don't know how to **convert the given rotation matrix from HeadphoneMotion, to be used by the transform of a SceneKit camera**. That would be the question. (Ideally, paired with the concepts behind the permutation of columns required, to learn how it's done.)

Also, I would like to avoid using `eulerAngles` or `quaternions` at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more into matrices, I came up with a solution.
Not sure if it's the right way, and not sure of the reasoning behind it (If someone knows and want to elaborate, please feel free).

Basically, assuming the schemes I drew of both coordinates systems are correct (specially the CoreMotion one), we can calculate a rotation matrix `T` that separates both system; this is, one matrix that would turn one system into the other.

By looking at those schemes, we know the SceneKit coordinate system is `90º` apart (on the `axis X`) from the CoreMotion coordinate system, and the rotation matrix `T` would be as follows (in swift, column by column):

```
let matrixT = simd_float4x4([
          simd_float4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          simd_float4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
          simd_float4( 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          simd_float4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        ])
```

Knowing this, we can obtain `R'`, which is just the initial rotation matrix `R` but in the target coordinate system, by doing this (and this is the key):

`R' = T^-1 * R * T`

Which in swift, would be:

```
let newRotation = matrixT.inverse * originalRotationMatrix * matrixT;
```

Just like that, the newRotation can be used as a transform in the SceneKit camera, and it works.